# RxJava custom ArrayList changes reference list also

Tags: android, arraylist, realm, rx-java, rx-java2

**Structure**

```
Class Dogs extends RealmObject{
    private RealmList<Cats> cats;
}
```

`dogList` contains non empty list of `cats`.
I am trying to remove cats/set as empty list but result also affects on parent list.

```
 protected void removeCatsFromDogs(ArrayList<Dogs> dogList) {
   ArrayList<Dogs> newList = new  ArrayList<>(dogList);

    Observable.fromIterable(newList)
            .map(dogs ->
                    {
                        dogs.setCats(null);
                        // dogs.setCats(new RealmList<>()); also not working
                        return dogs;
                    }
            ).toList()
            .doOnSuccess(dogs -> baseRealm.executeTransaction(realm -> baseRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(dogs)))
            .subscribe();


}
```

`doOnSuccess` returns `dogs` with `null` list but it also reflects in original list.

I have also tried to copy objects one by one using for loop but still same issue.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @ChristianMelchior i have updated my question. in short, I don't want to make any changes in `dogList` (function param)

Comment: So you have a unmanaged `dogList` (with cats), but you want to update all the dogs in Realm in a way that remove all their cats, and all of this without effecting your original `dogList`?

Comment: yes @ChristianMelchior. exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated above, you need to manually create a copy of your objects with the properties you want copied. Something like this should work:

```
public class Dogs extends RealmObject {
    public String name;
    public RealmList<Cats> cats;

    public static Dogs shallowCopy(Dogs dogs) {
        Dogs copy = new Dogs();
        copy.name = dogs.name;
        return copy;
    }
}


protected void removeCatsFromDogs(ArrayList<Dogs> dogList) {
    ArrayList<Dogs> newList = new  ArrayList<>(dogList);
    Observable.fromIterable(newList)
        .map(dogs -> { return Dogs.shallowCopy(dogs); })
        .toList()
        .doOnSuccess(dogs -> baseRealm.executeTransaction(realm -> baseRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(dogs)))
        .subscribe();
}
```

Comment: This can be better approach rather than iterating for loop and create object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new `Dog` in your `map()` operation. The new `Dog` will have `cats` as empty, presumably.

Because you are passing in an object as a parameter, changes the value that is passed in. This is how Java parameter passing works.

Comment: That's what i am already doing by creating dog object and add separately in new list. i.e no modification on original one using traditional for loop.

Comment: In your original post, you aren't creating a new `Dogs`. You are using the `Dogs` that is passed in.

Comment: check my updated question. i am creating entire copy of `dogList`.

Comment: The question text still shows that you are processing a list, one item at a time, modifying an item as it comes through, and then, re-assembling them into a new list. My point is that you are changing the original `Dogs`, and my point still stands.